# Why does subsetting my dataset by a number work, but subsetting by a variable name equal to that number cause chaos?

Tags: r, dplyr, indexing, subset

Disclaimer: I already figured out how to get around this detail, using the dplyr select() function. I'll put the code for the eventual solution at the bottom of this question.

So, I was trying to write a function that would subset a larger data frame by the arguments inside the function, and only return the columns passed as arguments to the function. This meant, I believe, that I needed to somehow within my function create a variable called *index* that would equal the column index number of the argument passed to my function.

So I had a dataframe called outcomes3, which contained data on the mortality outcomes of US hospitals for various conditions, and I wanted it to be able to take two arguments, the 2-letter US state abbreviation and the name of the condition you were curious about, and in return it would give the best hospital in that US state for that condition, i.e. that had the lowest mortality rate.

Writing the function to subset the final output by a specific column index I put in manually did work:

```
best_hospital <- function(x, y) {
      statesub <- outcomes3[State == x]
      sorted <- statesub[order(statesub, get(y)), ]
      index <- as.double(which(names(outcomes3) == y))
      head(sorted[ ,c(1,3), drop = FALSE],1)
}
```

calling best_hospital("NY","Attack") - short for Heart Attack - gave me the right output:

> ```
>            Hospital Attack
> ```
>
> 1: NYU HOSPITALS CENTER   10.1

Of course, this only worked because the column for Attack mortality rates happened to be column 3.

So I wrote this function to first see if I was getting the right index:

```
best_hospital <- function(x, y) {
      statesub <- outcomes3[State == x]
      sorted <- statesub[order(statesub, get(y)), ]
      index <- as.double(which(names(outcomes3) == y))
      head(sorted[ ,c(1,3), drop = FALSE],1)
      print(index)
}
```

and called it using "NY", "Attack" (short for "Heart Attack)" gave the following output:

`best_hospital("NY","Attack")`

> ## 3

So within my function, the variable *index* was equal to 3. Just to double check this, I tried the following:

`best_hospital("NY","Attack") == 3`

> ## TRUE

So the value of "index" was definitely 3, I think.

**So why on earth does this happen when I put sorted[ ,c(1,index), drop = FALSE] into my code rather than
sorted[ ,c(1,3), drop = FALSE], which theoretically should be identical inputs given that index was definitely equal to 3?
**

```
best_hospital <- function(x, y) {
      statesub <- outcomes3[State == x]
      sorted <- statesub[order(statesub, get(y)), ]
      index <- as.double(which(names(outcomes3) == y))
      head(sorted[ ,c(1,index), drop = FALSE],1)
}

best_hospital("NY","Attack")
```

> ## 1.

I got 1. Just the number one. A 1 length numeric vector, I checked.

**Now again, I did actually end up solving the problem with the following code:**

```
best_hospital <- function(x, y) {
      statesub <- outcomes2[State == x]
      sorted <- statesub[order(statesub, get(y)), ]
      index <- as.numeric(which(names(outcomes2) == y))
      head(dplyr::select(sorted, c(1,index)),1)
}

best_hospital("NY", "Heart Attack")
```

> ```
>            Hospital Heart Attack
> ```
>
> 1: NYU HOSPITALS CENTER         10.1

Note that the final function called outcomes2 rather than outcomes3 as above - outcomes 2 was just exactly the same as outcomes3, except it used two word column titles that were more descriptive. I just didn't want to mess with getting two words to work until the very end, so the data frame being outcome2 instead of outcome3 is not what caused any change.

And as desired, calling a different condition gave a different answer:

`best_hospital("NY", "Heart Failure")`

> ```
>                       Hospital Heart Failure
> ```
>
> 1: KINGSBROOK JEWISH MEDICAL CENTER            7

So I eventually solved the problem. But my question remains: I have no idea why trying to put *index* into my vector I was subsetting by caused so bizarre, unexpected output, when typing the number that *index* was equal to manually into the function worked perfectly.

For my future knowledge, why on earth was this happening?

Thank you so much for anyone who read this!

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question but you don't include any sample data, and it doesn't seem like you've edited it to a "minimal" size yet, both of which make it harder for people to help.

Comment: Swinging in the dark here, but I think you could use `best_hospital <- function(x,y) {  outcomes3 %>%    filter(State == x) %>%    slice_min( {{y}} , n = 1) %>%    pull(1, {{y}} ) }` for a more standard dplyr approach. Or the transform to long form and use `outcomes3_long %>% filter(State == x, name == y) %>% slice_min(value, n = 1)`

Comment: I'm confused how your code, as provided here, would work. `outcomes3[State == x]` doesn't seem like it should run. If it did, I should be able to run `x = "setosa"; iris[Species == x]` but that doesn't run, while `iris[Species == x,]` does.

Comment: I'm on my phone and not my laptop so I can't really respond completely right now, but I'll get back to you tomorrow with the sample data I used and the commands I used to load the file, so hopefully that'll help! I also had loaded the dplyr and data.table packages, so possibly one of those masked a base package command and led to something working that normally would not. I have a feeling maybe data.table led to the unexpected result you mentioned.